# How to label nodes in scatter plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, label, scatter-plot

I have some data as following:

```
xlab ylab xval yval class
1 2 6015 10500 3 
1 7 6015 9696 1 
3 5 6632 15626 3 
3 6 6632 6074 1 
3 5 6632 4189 2 
1 3 6015 6632 1 
1 5 6015 15626 1
```

I want to create a scatter plot using with x and y coordinate specified in **xval** and **yval** columns. Each point is colored based on the value in **class** column. This part I could do as following:

```
<!-- language: lang-R -->
data <- read.table(filename, header=TRUE);
df <- data.frame(data["xval"], data["yval"], data["class"]);
plot(xval, yval, col=c("red", "blue", "green")[class],
 main="Title here",
 xlab="Ox title",
 ylab="Oy title");
```

Now, I want to have a label for each node using the **xlab** and **ylab** columns in the form of **(xlab, ylab)**. Eg. The first node is labeled as **(1,2)**. However, I couldn't figured out how to do it.

Can someone please show me how to add labels to nodes pleases? I'm a newbie in R so I'd really appreciate if you could show me the sample code.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `text` function as follows:

```
with(df, plot(xval, yval, col=c("red", "blue", "green")[class],
 main="Title here",
 xlab="Ox title",
 ylab="Oy title"))

with(df, text(xval, yval, sprintf("(%s, %s)", xlab, ylab)))
```

I use sprint here but you could use `paste`/`paste0` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, Tyler. I just have one small question. How can I adjust the font and location of the label? I got the label wrap around the node as shown in [here](http://picpaste.com/plot-ZITrfKL9.png). I want the label to be a bit smaller and positioned above the node. Do you mind showing that part too please?

Comment: I got it. I can change the location by changing values of xval and yval in text(), and reduce the font size using cex=0.7 for example. Thank you,

Comment: I want to change the default symbol for each node. I've just learned that I can use **pch=as.integer(class)** to assign the values in **class** column to pch. However, I want some specific values like pch=15, 17, etc. Is there anyway to do it without having to change the input data? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I should've done that. But anyway, I figured it out after a few tries. Thank you.